# Is it possible to setup the IBM HTTP server as the front end for a non IBM Websphere application server and is it supported by IBM?

Tags: java, http, websphere, ibmhttpserver

Is it possible to setup the IBM HTTP server as the front end for a **non IBM Websphere application server** (Glassfish, Apache Tomcat or other Java application servers) and is it supported by IBM? I tried to look for similar articles online but to no luck. I also tried asking IBM support but they haven't gone back to me as of this posting. Feedback will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM HTTP is an enhanced variant of Apache HTTP Server. I have  used it in the past as a reverse proxy in front of Tomcat Server (as well as other non application servers for example Websphere Message Broker) in the past. I am not really sure if the entitlement allows support from IBM to permit this , you will have to specifically check if the entitlements allow support on non WAS instances.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but not supported. To summarize the license options across different releases: you have either totally unsupported or bundled with an IBM product (like WAS) and supported when used in a way direct and necessary to support that product.

It's generally inadvisable, too. Because you IBM cares very little about the alternate modules used for this kind of thing and you can't service them yourself as a user. Contrast with just using Apache or nginx.